# Trying to remove HTML tags (+ content) from String

Tags: php, regex

OK, so basically I'm about to bang my head against the wall with this one.

**Here's the code :**

```
<?php

$s = "385,178<ref name=\"land area\">Data is accessible by following \"Create tables and diagrams\" link on the following site, and then using table 09280 \"Area of land and fresh water (kmÂ²) (M)\" for \"The whole country\" in year 2013 and summing up entries \"Land area\" and \"Freshwater\": {{cite web |url=http://www.ssb.no/en/natur-og-miljo/statistikker/arealdekke |title=Area of land and fresh water, 1 January 2013 |publisher=[[Statistics Norway]] |date=28 May 2013 |accessdate=23 November 2013}}</ref>";

function removeHTMLTags($str) { 
    $r = '/(\\<br\\>)|(\\<br\/\\>)|(\\<(.+?)(\\s*[^\\<]+)?\\>(.+)?\\<\\\\\/\\1\\>)|(\\<ref\\sname=([^\\<]+?)\/\\>)/';

    echo "Preg_matching : $str\n\n";
    echo "Regex : $r\n\n";

    return preg_replace($r,'',$str); 
}

echo removeHTMLTags($s);

?>
```

What I'm trying to do, is basically *get rid of the `<ref name="...  </ref>` part (and all possible tags as well)*.

However, **this is what I'm getting**

(a.k.a. *exactly the same string, with nothing being replaced whatsoever*) :

```
Preg_matching : 385,178<ref name="land area">Data is accessible by following "Create tables and diagrams" link on the following site, and then using table 09280 "Area of land and fresh water (kmÂ²) (M)" for "The whole country" in year 2013 and summing up entries "Land area" and "Freshwater": {{cite web |url=http://www.ssb.no/en/natur-og-miljo/statistikker/arealdekke |title=Area of land and fresh water, 1 January 2013 |publisher=[[Statistics Norway]] |date=28 May 2013 |accessdate=23 November 2013}}</ref>

Regex : /(\<br\>)|(\<br\/\>)|(\<(.+?)(\s*[^\<]+)?\>(.+)?\<\\\/\1\>)|(\<ref\sname=([^\<]+?)\/\>)/

385,178<ref name="land area">Data is accessible by following "Create tables and diagrams" link on the following site, and then using table 09280 "Area of land and fresh water (kmÂ²) (M)" for "The whole country" in year 2013 and summing up entries "Land area" and "Freshwater": {{cite web |url=http://www.ssb.no/en/natur-og-miljo/statistikker/arealdekke |title=Area of land and fresh water, 1 January 2013 |publisher=[[Statistics Norway]] |date=28 May 2013 |accessdate=23 November 2013}}</ref>
```

So, the question is : **what am I doing wrong wrong**? (I've tested the regex with RegExr multiple times, and it does seem to be working - am I messing it up with the... escapes?)

---

**P.S.** For those of you who know what I'm talking about : yep, that's a portion of Wikipedia Infobox.

Comment: What should the end-result be? Also, why aren't you simply using `strip_tags()`? Does that not satisfy your requirements? If not, why?

Comment: You shouldn't be playing HTML with regex. Well what's the problem you faced with `strip_tags()` ?

Comment: @AmalMurali The initial string (`$s`) without any tags(+tag content) in it.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Well, isn't `strip_tags()` leaving the tag contents in tact? (this is *not* what I want...)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: That is just `385,178`?

Comment: @AmalMurali Yep. But please don't over simplify it. It's not like I want the number. It's just that I want everything BUT the html/tags part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should use the DOM for this kind of stuff, because other solutions tend to break easily:

```
$dom = new DOMDOcument();
$errorState = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($s);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$node = $xpath->query('//body/p/text()')->item(0);
echo $node->textContent;

libxml_use_internal_errors($errorState);
```

Comment: I've decided to accept *your* answer as correct, as it seemingly works better. However, there still are issues. Please, have a look at here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796147/remove-all-html-tagscontent-from-text